# Efficient way to import data with linq in C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq, collections

I have a Collection of some objects and the objects are from one specific class.

Now I want to import this Collection with Linq.
I know the principle of importing data with Linq.

My question is, when I am importing this Collection of Objects which are for example two tables in the database connected with a foreignkey and some Objects would then share the same foreignkey is it better for performance and scaling to first import in one table, get the ID from this import back and update the Collection on the Client with this ID or keep the ID from the imported data in for example a other collection and check it always for the next object in the Collection?

Or what would be the best soultion for working with Linq and a Collection that is imported in several different tables?

Comment: Your title is really misleading.  Linq does not import/export data, it pretty much can only transform data.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> which are ... two tables in the database connected with a foreign key

This looks like a relationship: the foreign key in one table refers to the primary key of the other table.

For example a School with its many Students. If the Student with primary key [10] attends School with primary key [8], then Student [10] has a foreign key SchoolId with a value [8]

You also wrote:

> ... and some Objects would then share the same foreign key

This is a bit confusing. It seems that you mean, that the items in the two tables have a foreign key, that is referring to the same primary key of an item in a third table.

For example: If Student [10] attends School [8] and Teacher [25] teaches at School [8], then both the Student and the Teacher will have a foreign key SchoolId with a value of [8]

Your question is, what is more efficient: fetching the data from the tables using two queries and then combine them, or let the database do this in one query.

Databases are extremely optimized to combine records from tables, especially if these records refer to each other using foreign keys. One of the slower parts is the transfer of the queries data from the database management system to your local process.

Hence it is wise to transport only properties of records that you actually plan to use.

Now you seem to have two tables, where the records all have a foreign key pointing to the primary key of an item in a third table, like my Example of Schools, Teachers, and Students.

Normally you would query Schools that ... ; each School with its Teachers that ... and its Students that ...;

You probably don't want all properties from the Schools and Teachers and Students. It seems you don't want any School Properties, only some Teacher Properties and Student Properties.

As you want to match Students that have a certain SchoolId with Teachers that have the same SchoolId, it would be wise not to pass this foreign key twice: once for the Student of School [8] and once for the Teacher of School [8], since they are at the same School, you know they will have the same value.

Another optimization: if you have several Students at School [8] and several Teachers at School [8], why not do the following query:

> Give me for all Schools that ..., the primary key (and maybe some other properties), together with (some properties of) all Students that attend this School, and (some properties of) all Teachers who teach at this School

```
var results = dbContext.Schools
    .Select(school => new
    {
        Id = school.Id,
        Name = school.Name,        // only if you want other School properties
        ...

        // All Students that attend this School
        // == that have a foreign key equal to School.Id
        Students = dbContext.Students.Select(student => new
        {
            // Select only the properties that you plan to use
            Id = student.Id,
            Name = student.Name,
            ...

            // not needed: you know the value:
            // SchoolId = student.SchoolId,
        })
        .ToList(),

        // all Teachers that teach on this School
        // == that have a foreign key equal to School.Id
        // == that have a foreign key equal to the foreign key of all Students on this School
        Teachers = dbContext.Teachers.Select(teacher => new
        {
            // again: select only properties that you plan to use
            Id = teacher.Id,
            Name = teacher.Name,
            ...

            // not needed: you know the value:
            // SchoolId = teacher.SchoolId,

        })
        .ToList(),
    });
```

In the Result, you know that the School with Id [8] will have all Students that have a foreign key with value [8] and all Teachers that have a foreign key with value [8]

Comment: This is not was I meant. Maybe I wrote it to hard to understand for other people what the problem is.
I have a Collection with Objects. Let us stay to your school example.
In die Collection are then objects with students and schools. Neither the students nor the schools are already in the database. The objects in the Collection are for example: Name of Students; Name of the school. And then I want to import them. So I have first to import the new school and then the students. what is the best way to do this? create the school first and then update the stundents in the collection with the id?